# What is the meaning of "Equivalent To" in Protege?

Tags: semantics, semantic-web, owl, protege

I am studying OWL and I am trying to build an Ontology using Protege.

I found an option called `Equivalent To` in Protege.

What is that option for please? Is it for dividing the space of instances? or is it to set the Object properties that a class can have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Equivalent to` applies to class expressions, object properties and data properties.

### Equivalence in class expressions

In class expressions, equivalence means that two classes have the same individuals in any interpretation (i.e., the two classes are alternate names, or equivalent definitions, for the same set of individuals).

### Equivalence in data and object properties

For object and data properties, asserting that two properties are equivalent means that their domains and ranges apply to both properties, and that every assertion using one property can be rewritten as using the other.

#### Example

For example, suppose I declare a `hasOwner` object property and an `ownedBy` as equivalent, then: `MyCar hasOwner Me` implies `MyCar ownedBy Me`.

Comment: I accepted you answer, but please what do you mean by "assertion"?

Comment: An assertion is an ABox axiom, i.e., an axiom that relates two individuals or an individual and a literal, or a type assertion. `X type Person`, `X friendsWith Y`, `X hasHeight "170"^^xsd:int` are all assertions.